# Macro look for text to attach files and send in email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I know some basic excel VBA but I've never made a macro like this in the past. I made some research but haven't come across with a solution, I hope you guys can help me.

I need this macro to go to a table, capture the name in the column A "Customer name", open a Folder in the macro's path and look for a file that has the same name on it. The problem lies in the name of the files. Those always have "Customer name" & File date 03-24-20.xlsx on it. (The date changes every week)

Once that it is identified, attach it and send it in an email to the email in the column E "Email".

[image]

And this is not a requirement but would make things more easier. Sometimes, some customers might have the same email, is there a way to attach all the files that match in 1 email?

I added an image as a reference, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Dir function in vba can get the full name of file using wildcards.
chdir function in vba set the directory you want vba to search file in.
for example:

```
chdir "C:\foldername"
attachmentFileName = "C:\foldername" & dir("Random company*")
''---Here * is a wildcard (means it will be replaced with the rest of the file name.)
mailItem.attachment = attachmentfileName
```

Comment: Thank you so much Shivang!

But this would make the macro use strict values, like stating "Random company".

Is there any way to make this more dynamic? That table might contain 80 - 120 records!  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I used Random company to make you understand the concept. You can always use cell reference like this: dir(.cells(1,1).value & "*"). Moreover use loops to loop over all rows and attach files to outlook mail.